# How to show one view after app launch

Tags: ios, swift

in swift3

I want to create an app that needs to check my password every time the app launches.

The main screen consists of navigationController,

I have created an independent UIViewController that checks the password.

I want to show a screen to check my password when I first run the app or when it runs in the background.

In addition, if the password is confirmed, I want to return to the screen of the original NavigationController.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what do you mean by when it runs in the background?

Comment: @Whencesoever When the app is in the background and running.

Comment: Does the user need to type in the password or is the password check being done on the basis of a stored password, for instance, in keys?

Comment: you can set your password check viewcontroller to rootViewcontroller from app delegate  and after verifying the password show the navigation controller.

Comment: You can check this in :  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool{}

Answer (score 0):

You can create one viewController which looks like Splash screen and check password over there and then navigate to your navigationController.

Comment: I do not know how to launch the password confirmation window every time I run the app.

Comment: let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
                let rootVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
                
                window?.rootViewController = rootVC


Add this code in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method.